# How can'i save the result of a PrintWriter in file instead of display it in the console

Tags: java, servlets, printwriter

I have this example which displays the result in a console

```
HttpServletResponse presponse
presponse.setContentType(text/xml; charset=UTF-8)

PrintWriter lout = presponse.getWriter();
lout.println(var);
lout.close();
```

But i want to save the result in downloadable file  instead of display it in the console
can you help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to provide the file content as the HTTP response payload, you should not write it into `response.getWriter()`. By the way, you're *not* "displaying it in the console", you're sending it as the HTTP response to the client's request.

To save a file with that content on the local disk, just create a `FileOutputStream` and write the file content in there.

As for the HTTP response, just provide the URL to the newly created downloadable file (as a `Location` header or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like, you need to set correct `mime-type` and `content-length` header.

```
    File downloadFile = new File(filePath);
    FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(downloadFile);

    // obtains response's output stream
    OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead = -1;

    while ((bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }

    inStream.close();
    outStream.close();
```